# How can I split a long function into separate steps while maintaining the relationship between said steps?

Tags: python

I have a very long function `func` which takes a browser handle and performs a bunch of requests and reads a bunch of responses in a specific order:

```
def func(browser):
    # make sure we are logged in otherwise log in
    # make request to /search and check that the page has loaded
    # fill form in /search and submit it
    # read table of response and return the result as list of objects
```

Each operation require a large amount of code due to the complexity of the DOM and they tend to grow really fast.

What would be the best way to refactor this function into smaller components so that the following properties still hold:

- the execution flow of the operations and/or their preconditions is guaranteed just like in the current version
- the preconditions are not checked with asserts against the state, as this is a very costly operation
- `func` can be called multiple times on the browser

?

Comment: You could create a `@only_call_once` decorator. Not sure how to minimize the scope, though..

Comment: If the sole purpose is readability I would split the func into three "private" or "protected" ones (i.e. `_func1` or `__func1`) and a private or protected property which keeps the state shared between the functions.

Comment: What about TCO http://neopythonic.blogspot.fr/2009/04/final-words-on-tail-calls.html ?

Comment: @AliSAIDOMAR I'm not sure how this applies to my case. Are you perhaps suggesting that each step calls the next?

Comment: In fact each step knows the following step to be called against condition

Comment: @user3159253 Well, this prevention is not much about the worry of people external to the module to call these step functions. It's more about having the same safety guarantees as a module writer. Since these preconditions are so difficult to check, it would be great to be able to encode it in a way in which the order and execution flow is guaranteed by Python

Comment: @Shoe <sarcasm>you could just leave all the code un-functioned!</sarcasm> :)

Comment: @AliSAIDOMAR In my case it doesn't make sense for each step to know to execute the next or to even depend on the next. Each step function depends only on a shared resources which much be in a specific state before the execution of each state function. How it arrived at that function is not relevant and could be through different ways.

Comment: It's not clear what the rules for using `funcA` et al. *outside* `func` are. For example, can `funcA` not be called again until `funcB` and `funcC` have been called?

Comment: @chepner `funcA` depends on the initial state given to `func` only. Which means that since `funcB` and `funcC` change the state, after `funcB` is called, `funcA` cannot be called again with the state transformed by `funcB`. And once `funcB` is called, the state is only ready to be executed by `funcC` and not `funcA`. At the end of `funcC`, in this case, the state returned by `funcC` kind of doesn't matter, because after `funcC` the function logic had ended and another flow starting again from `funcA` could happen.

Comment: @chepner I've added the actual context of the problem by the way. It might clear things up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just wrap the three helper methods in a class, and track which methods are allowed to run in an instance.

```
class Helper(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = True
        self.b = False
        self.c = False

    def funcA(self):
        if not self.A:
            raise Error("Cannot run funcA now")
        # do stuff here
        self.a = False
        self.b = True
        return whatever

    def funcB(self):
        if not self.B:
            raise Error("Cannot run funcB now")
        # do stuff here
        self.b = False
        self.c = True
        return whatever

    def funcC(self):
        if not self.C:
            raise Error("Cannot run funcC now")
        # do stuff here
        self.c = False
        self.a = True
        return whatever

def func(...):
    h = Helper()
    h.funcA()
    h.funcB()
    h.funcC()

# etc
```

The only way to call a method is if its flag is true, and each method clears its own flag and sets the next method's flag before exiting. As long as you don't touch `h.a` et al. directly, this ensures that each method can only be called in the proper order.

Alternately, you can use a single flag that is a reference to the function currently allowed to run.

```
class Helper(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.allowed = self.funcA
    def funcA(self):
        if self.allowed is not self.funcA:
            raise Error("Cannot run funcA now")
        # do stuff
        self.allowed = self.funcB
        return whatever
    # etc
```

Comment: Nice KISS solution! +1

Comment: Hm. I didn't test this; `self.allowed is not self.funcA` may not work, since a new method object is instantiated for each lookup of `self.funcA`. Using `Helper.funcA`, etc, instead might work, but the whole approach may fail. The Boolean flags, though, will definitely work fine.

Comment: I think SO is about solutions, not answers.

Comment: I do like to avoid suggesting blatantly broken code, though ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution I came up with. I used a decorator (closely related to the one in [this blog post](http://pydev.blogspot.com/2012/12/python-tricks-making-sure-function-is.html)) which only allows for a function to be called once.

```
def call_only_once(func):  
  def new_func(*args, **kwargs):  
    if not new_func._called:  
      try:  
        return func(*args, **kwargs)  
      finally:  
        new_func._called = True  
    else:
      raise Exception("Already called this once.")
  new_func._called = False  
  return new_func  

@call_only_once  
def stateA(): 
   print 'Calling stateA only this time' 

@call_only_once  
def stateB(): 
   print 'Calling stateB only this time'    

@call_only_once  
def stateC(): 
   print 'Calling stateC only this time' 

def state():
  stateA()
  stateB()
  stateC()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  state()
```

You'll see that if you re-call any of the functions, the function will throw an `Exception` stating that the functions have already been called.

The problem with this is that if you ever need to call `state()` again, you're hosed. Unless you implement these functions as private functions, I don't think you can do *exactly* what you want due to the nature of Python's scoping rules.

## Edit

You can also remove the `else` in the decorator and your function will always return `None`.

Comment: I see, but `state` as a function is called multiple times. Maybe I should specify this in the question body.

Comment: @Shoe Understood... that makes the problem a little harder... You _could_ remove the `else` and just check that the functions are returning something. Not ideal, but it might be a decent first step.

Comment: I've *refactored* my question to clarify the actual problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here a snippet I used once for my state machine

```
class StateMachine(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.handlers = {}
        self.start_state = None
        self.end_states = []

    def add_state(self, name, handler, end_state=0):
        name = name.upper()
        self.handlers[name] = handler
        if end_state:
            self.end_states.append(name)

    def set_start(self, name):
        # startup state
        self.start_state = name

    def run(self, **kw):
        """
        Run
        :param kw:
        :return:
        """
        # the first .run call call the first handler with kw keywords
        # each registered handler should returns the following handler and the needed kw 
        try:
            handler = self.handlers[self.start_state]
        except:
            raise InitializationError("must call .set_start() before .run()")
        while True:
            (new_state, kw) = handler(**kw)
            if isinstance(new_state, str):
                if new_state in self.end_states:
                    print("reached ", new_state)
                    break
                else:
                    handler = self.handlers[new_state]
            elif hasattr(new_state, "__call__"):
                handler = new_state
            else:
                return
```

The use

```
class MyParser(StateMachine):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # define handlers
        # we can define many handler as we want
        self.handlers["begin_parse"] = self.begin_parse
        # define the startup handler
        self.set_start("begin_parse")

    def end(self, **kw):
        logging.info("End of parsing ")
        # no callable handler => end 
        return None, None

    def second(self, **kw):
        logging.info("second  ")
        # do something
        # if condition is reach the call `self.end` handler
        if ...:
            return self.end, {}

    def begin_parse(self, **kw):
        logging.info("start  of parsing ")
        # long process until the condition is reach then call the `self.second` handler with kw new keywords
        while True:
            kw = {}
            if ...:
                return self.second, kw
            # elif other cond:
                # return self.other_handler, kw
            # elif other cond 2:
                # return self.other_handler 2, kw
             else:
                return self.end, kw
# start the state machine
MyParser().run()
```

will print

```
   INFO:root:start  of parsing 
   INFO:root:second  
   INFO:root:End of parsing
```

Comment: Not sure how this helps. Maybe include an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

You could use local functions in your `func` function. Ok, they are still declared inside one single global function, but Python is nice enough to still give you access to them for tests.

Here is one example of one function declaring and executing 3 (supposedly heavy) subfunctions. It takes one optional parameter `test` that when set to `TEST` prevent actual execution but instead gives external access to individual sub-functions and to a local variable:

```
def func(test=None):
    glob = []
    def partA():
        glob.append('A')
    def partB():
        glob.append('B')
    def partC():
        glob.append('C')
    if (test == 'TEST'):
        global testA, testB, testC, testCR
        testA, testB, testC, testCR = partA, partB, partC, glob
        return None
    partA()
    partB()
    partC()
    return glob
```

When you call `func`, the 3 parts are executed in sequence. But if you first call `func('TEST')`, you can then access the local `glob` variable as `testCR`, and the 3 subfunctions as `testA`, `testB` and `testC`. This way you can still test individually the 3 parts with well defined input and control their output.

Answer (score 0):

I would insist on the suggestion given by @user3159253 in his comment on the original question:

> If the sole purpose is readability I would split the func into three "private" > or "protected" ones (i.e. _func1 or __func1) and a private or protected property > which keeps the state shared between the functions.

This makes a lot of sense to me and seems more usual amongst object oriented programming than the other options. Consider this example as an alternative:

Your class (teste.py):

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__environment = {}             # Protected information to be shared
        self.public_stuff = 'public info'   # Accessible to outside callers

    def func(self):
        print "Main function"
        self.__func_a()
        self.__func_b()
        self.__func_c()
        print self.__environment

    def __func_a(self):
        self.__environment['function a says'] = 'hi'

    def __func_b(self):
        self.__environment['function b says'] = 'hello'

    def __func_c(self):
        self.__environment['function c says'] = 'hey'
```

Other file:

```
from teste import Test

t = Test()
t.func()
```

This will output:

```
Main function says hey guys
{'function a says': 'hi', 'function b says': 'hello', 'function c says': 'hey'}
```

If you try to call one of the protected functions, an error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Lucas/PycharmProjects/testes/other.py", line 6, in <module>
    t.__func_a()
AttributeError: Test instance has no attribute '__func_a'
```

Same thing if you try to access the protected environment variable:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Lucas/PycharmProjects/testes/other.py", line 5, in <module>
    print t.__environment
AttributeError: Test instance has no attribute '__environment'
```

In my view this is the most elegant, simple and readable way to solve your problem, let me know if it fits your needs :)

Comment: The problem is not really about protecting said functions from the outside word. It's just about enforcing the correctness of the program as much as possible within the module/class itself. The current version has the nice property of ensuring a certain order of execution. The division into different components loses this guarantee.

Comment: Well, in that case I would say that by grouping the three functions in the correct order in the main function and restricting the calls to only the main function you would achieve that effect. I suppose your problem is exactly how to restrict calls only to the main function right? If I were you I would consider simpler and more readable options such as upgrading this function to a class, but now I'm just giving my opinion.

Comment: Keep in mind one of the lines of the zen of python: "If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea."